# Select limited amount of rows with at most n rows of type A

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is it possible to select a limited amount `M` of rows with at most `N` rows of some type `T`(string or enum field) in one select statement(`M > N`)?
So far I've tried using `DBMS_RANDOM` like so, but it's not pretty and does not do exactly what I need

```
select id from some_table 
         where ((type = 'A' and round(dbms_random.value(0,100)) > 75)
                or (type <> 'A'))
               and rownum < 1000;
```

EDIT:
What i'm dealing with is a kind of queue implemented using database. there are K different types of messages. The A type of messages are low priority and they are inserted around 100k records at a time once or twice a day. other types of messages have higher priority and are inserted constantly. So what i've tried to achieve is to process those records in such a way that when messages of type A are inserted messages of other types won't starve.

Comment: I think you should render your request more precisely. You want M rows exactly. Of these rows no more than N rows of type 'A'. This would be true for zero rows of type 'A' and thus probably easy to achieve, but this is certainly not what you'd like to see. So: Must it be *exactly* N rows? If not, how many min and max? And then: is it guaranteed that we will find as many rows (total and 'A') as desired or can there be too few?

Comment: what i'm dealing with is a kind of queue implemented using database. there are K different types of messages. the A type of messages are low priority and they are inserted around 100k records at a time once or twice a day. other types of messages have higher priority and are inserted constantly. so what i've tried to achieve is to process those records in such a way that when messages of type A are inserted messages of other types won't starve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could use `rownum` and `union all` but that can get complicated.  I think `row_number()` is better suited for this purpose:

```
select t.*
from (select id, row_number() over (partition by type order by dms_random.value()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where (type = 'A' and seqnum <= 100) and
      rownum < 1000;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've used the idea with partitioning to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Random ordering doesn't guarantee that you get N type A records and M type not-A records. In order to guarantee this you need to explicitly state it, which means splitting out the queries to generate the row numbers.

The naive version would to use the [UNION ALL operator](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries004.htm#SQLRF52341):

```
select id
  from t
 where type = 'A'
   and rownum < N
 union all
select id
  from t
 where type <> 'A'
   and rownum < M
```

The main downside to this method is that it requires two scans of the table. You can potentially get around this by using [sub-query factoring](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2077142) (a CTE), but it might be simpler to use an analytic query such as [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions170.htm#SQLRF06100). If you partition on your type then you can use the generated row number to limit independently:

```
select id
  from ( select id
              , type
              , row_number() over (partition by case when type = 'A' then 'A'
                                                     else 'B'
                                                end) as rnum
           from t
                )
 where ( type = 'A' and rnum < N )
    or rnum < M
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've used the idea with partitioning to get it working.